# IIS7 Url Rewrite Add www prefix But Not In IP

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I got a pretty interesting situation here, hope you can help me with this.

If a user enters domain.com, I redirect it to the www.domain.com with the help of this code in my web.config:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="Add WWW prefix" >
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
           appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

This is simple and clean, works like a charm. But domain.com has a dedicated IP too like 19.12.121.121. When I try to connect my site with the IP, web.config redirects me to this: www.19.12.121.121.

So the question is, how can I prevent this? It's going to redirect the domain but the IP?

Thank you.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090377/iis-url-canonical-rewrite-but-preserve-ip-address-access

Answer (score 0):

Since I can see that you are using URL rewrite already:

This is the rule that I use and it works for me including IP addresses.

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="www.(YOUR DESIRED URL).com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.(YOUR DESIRED URL).com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```